# Post data from form without knowing how long the form will be

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, forms

I need to post some form data using jQuery and the field input values needs to be posted in a JSON format. The problem is that the form fields comprise of fields that will definitely be there like: First Name, Last Name and Email, however the fields after this could be of any number because the form is constructed from a GET request. So normally I would do something like this:

```
var firstName = $('input[name="firstName"]').val();
var lastName = $('input[name="lastName"]').val();
var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();

data: JSON.stringify({
  "firstName": firstName,
  "lastName": lastName,
  "email": email
})
```

However this wont work for my remaining fields. So ideally I need to do like an each function or something to loop through these other questions and put this loop into the JSON.stringify but I have no idea how to do that. But then you might say why don't you just use:

```
$('form').serialize();
```

to just get all the form data but the problem is that the JSON needs to be in the following format

```
{
  "firstName": "string",
  "lastName": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "responses": [
    {
      "questionKey": 0, //this needs to be the ID of the input
      "responseText": "string", //this needs to the value of the input
    } //with this part of the JSON repeating for each question
  ]
}
```

All these additional fields have the same input class so I can work with them easily in jQuery. I am really stuck and I would really appreciate your help. Thank you :)

UPDATE - below is an example of the form fields:

```
<input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" class="known-questions">
<input name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text" class="known-questions">
<input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="known-questions">
<input name="45435345345" id="45435345345" type="text" class="unknown-questions">
<input name="43443539864" id="43443539864" type="text" class="unknown-questions">
<input name="43344243529" id="43344243529" type="text" class="unknown-questions"> //there could be any number of these 'unknown-questions' class inputs
```

Comment: Why you don't use an array of objects?

Comment: Knowing the html structure generated would help a lot. Then not difficult to iterate through elements and add properties/values based on names or other relevant attributes. For known fields can simplify down to array of those names and loop that array to set properties/values without writing it all out manually

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach isn't expected results for responses an array of objects? OP is trying to figure out how to create those objects

Comment: Btw `.serialize()` does not produce JSON

Comment: @Musa You are right, I should of expanded on this, to say how I would then convert that to JSON

Comment: @charlietfl Good call, I have now added the HTML

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach If that's the solution that would be fantastic, I am still learning jQuery so if you could expand on this would be done that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete form serialized to required structure:

```
var data ={};
$('.known-questions').each(function(){
    data[this.name] = this.value;
});

data.responses = $('.unknown-questions').map(function(){
   return {questionKey: this.id, responseText:this.value};
}).get();

var postJson = JSON.stringify(data);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/e5km51sy/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, this is really helpful, and I appreciate you making a demo as well

Answer (score 1):

You've said that each input element with a response for your `responses` array will share a class. Try this `each` loop, assuming `unknown-questions` as this class name:

```
var responsesArray = [];

$(".unknown-questions")
    .each(function(idx, obj)
    {
        responsesArray.push(
            {
                "questionKey" : obj.id,
                "responseText" : $(obj).val()
            });
    });
```

You've also said that you'd send the form data using jQuery. It's unclear if you want to GET or POST, or if you'll be using the jQuery AJAX functions, but I tested the above using the `jquery.get` call as below:

```
$.get("https://httpbin.org/get",
    {
        "firstName" : firstName,
        "lastName" : lastName,
        "email" : email,
        "responses" : responsesArray
    });
```

But I'm not sure this is what you want. If you want a JSON string that will capture the object that you can send as a single parameter, then this:

```
var jsonString =
    JSON.stringify(
    {
        "firstName" : firstName,
        "lastName" : lastName,
        "email" : email,
        "responses" : responsesArray
    });
```

produces the following JSON structure (I've inserted newlines and cooked up example form fields and values):

```
"{
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Smith",
    "email":"j.s@example.com",
    "responses":
        [
            {"questionKey":"response1", "responseText":"asdasd213"},
            {"questionKey":"response2", "responseText":"q34234234a"},
            {"questionKey":"response3", "responseText":"aaaa"},
            {"questionKey":"response4", "responseText":"bbbb"},
            {"questionKey":"response5", "responseText":"lkjlkj"}
        ]
}"
```

Comment: Similar for `known-questions` would simplify manually adding them to main object

Comment: Thanks pb2q, I see what you are doing here by pushing data into the array. So how does this interact with my First Name, Last Name and Email fields JSON which is like:  {
  "firstName": firstName,
  "lastName": lastName,
  "email": email
}
and ensure that it's on the correct level of the JSON?

Comment: @user1190132 I'll add a `$.get` example shortly

Comment: Thanks pb2q this answers my question as well. I appreciate the time you have sent helping me with this, I am still learning things and learning new techniques

Comment: @user1190132 glad to help. charlietfl answer is certainly more complete/concise